# How many domains (not sub domains) does firebase hosting support in the same project?

Tags: firebase, hosting, firebase-hosting

My app allows users set custom domains for their pages on Firebase Hosting.

Does there exists a limit to how many domains can be added to the project?

Answer (score 1):

There is no hard limit, but Firebase recommends no more than 20 domains per project (apex or subdomains). Projects run into issues when provisioning SSL certs too quickly and there's really no benefits (we know of) to putting this many sites into a single project vs multiple projects.

There is a relevant note here in [Connect a custom domain](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain)

[image]

And while you can connect more domains, you can only create 36 "sites" as noted in [multiple sites per project doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites).

[image]

Comment: I believe you're misinterpreting the documentation. It clearly states "no more than 20 subdomains on any one apex custom domain". As of today, that documentation doesn't say anything about apex custom domain limit

Comment: Not sure what you mean about misinterpreting the docs. I stated there is no hard limit (other than 36 sites per project). I also stated we (as in I work on Firebase) don't recommend more than 20 for the reasons stated.

Comment: I mean, the OP asked about domains (apex, not subdomains), but he didn't say anything about "sites". You can have many apex domains per single site. Firebase documentation recommends "no more than 20 *subdomains* on any one apex custom domain" which, as I understand, sets a limit of 20 subdomains per domain, but it states nothing about how many domains you can set up per site.  Besides mentioning sites (which is not what was asked by OP), you seem to be mixing domains and subdomains in your answer, but Firebase only talks about subdomains. That's why I believe your answer is confusing.

Comment: @Kato I'm planing to use identify platform and custom domains for each customer. Mostly for branding purposes. Let's assume I'll add a new custom domain each week, is it fine to assume it's no problem to have eventually 100+ custom domains pointing to the same project? (I really want to avoid setting up a custom firebase project for each customer as it would be an update nightmare)

Comment: It's the SSL certificates that are problematic.  So 100+ subdomains would be an issue but apex should be fine.

Comment: this is wrong answer